# Multiple comparisons in a c++ priority queue?

Tags: c++, queue, priority-queue

I am trying to simulate "jobs" coming into a printer. The jobs have been added to a priority queue based on processing time. I would also like to have another comparison where jobs with a priority of 1 are placed higher than jobs with a priority of 0 despite their processing time.

Here's a snippet of my code

```
struct Jobs{
    int priority; 
    int processingStatus;
    int arrivalTime; 
    int processingTime; 
    char jobType; 
};

struct Comp {
    bool operator()(const Jobs& a, const Jobs& b) {
        return a.processingTime > b.processingTime;
    }
};
void createJobs(Jobs jobsA[], Jobs jobsB[], Jobs jobsC[], Jobs jobsD[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        jobsA[i].arrivalTime = 4 + rand() % 3 + i; 
        jobsA[i].processingTime = 1 + rand() % 4; 
        jobsA[i].priority = 0; 
        jobsA[i].jobType = 'A'; 

        jobsD[i].arrivalTime = 25 + rand() % 10 + i ; 
        jobsD[i].processingTime = 8 + rand() % 4;
        jobsD[i].priority = 1; 
        jobsD[i].jobType = 'D';

    }
}
```

Comment: well... just modify your `Comp::operator()` to suit your requirement. What's the actual question?

Comment: @Fureeish That is my question, I am wondering how you would modify the Comp to return highest priority first and processing time

Comment: So just to be clear. You want to first compare the `priority` (bigger one is considered as 'before') and then compare the `processingTime` if priorities are equal?

Comment: @Fureeish Yes that is correct.

Comment: You’d just base the result on the priority if the priorities differ and take the processing time into account when the priorities are equal. Assuming the processing times are signed you could use `return std::tie(a.priority, -a.proccessingTime) < std::tie(b.priority, -b.processingTime)`

Comment: @DietmarKühl `std::tie` takes `T&`, which will not bind to a temporary created with unary `-` operator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your comparator order higher priority jobs before those with lower priority:

```
bool operator()(const Jobs& a, const Jobs& b) {
    if (a.priority == b.priority {
         return a.processingTime > b.processingTime;
    } else {
         return a.priority > b.priority;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code:

```
struct Jobs {
    int priority;
    int processingStatus;
    int arrivalTime;
    int processingTime;
    char jobType;

    bool operator <(const Jobs& other) const {
        const auto neg_lhs = -processingTime;
        const auto neg_rhs = -other.processingTime;
        return std::tie(priority, neg_lhs) < std::tie(other.priority, neg_rhs);
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, const Jobs& arg) {
        return out << arg.arrivalTime;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Jobs> source {
            // consecutive arrival times to distinguish the elements easily
            Jobs {1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
            Jobs {0, 1, 2, 1, 1},
            Jobs {2, 2, 3, 1, 1},
            Jobs {0, 2, 4, 1, 1}
    };

    std::priority_queue<Jobs> jobs(source.begin(), source.end());

    while(!jobs.empty()) {
        std::cout << jobs.top() << ' ';
        jobs.pop();
    }
}
```

Notice the presence of `operator<` inside the actual class `Jobs` that will lexicographically compare two `Jobs` objects using `std::tie` trick that relies on [`std::tuple::operator<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/operator_cmp).

I also added `operator<<` to make it simple to output `Jobs` objects, so the testing in `main()` is more convenient. The output of this program is:

```
3 1 4 2
```